# I want to arrangement jpanel for 2 columns to container in jscrollpane

Tags: java, swing, layout, containers, jscrollpane

I want to arrangement jpanel for 2 colums to container in jscrollpane.. 
my source

```
tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TreePath path = e.getPath();
            Object lastPathComponent = path.getLastPathComponent();
            switch (lastPathComponent.toString()) {
            case "전체보기":
                ViewArr.clear();
                cont.removeAll();
                for (int i = 0; i < candy.size(); i++) {
                    cont.add(vi.CreateViewer(candy.get(i)));
                    jsp2.getViewport().setView(cont);
                }
                break;
            }
            /** 동적생성된 날짜별 노드에 대한 액션 */
            for (int i = 0; i < date.size(); i++) {
                if (lastPathComponent.toString().equals(date.get(i))) {
                    ViewArr.clear();
                    cont.removeAll();
                    for (int j = 0; j < candy.size(); j++) {
                        if (candy.get(j).getInterviewDate().toString()
                                .substring(0, 7).equals(date.get(i))) {
                            cont.add(vi.CreateViewer(candy.get(j)));
                        }
                    }
                    jsp2.getViewport().setView(cont);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

container is gridlayout(0,2,10,10)..
my source's  jpanel to grow sideways....
Please help me! please teach me
Lastly, i'm sorry to have you watching troubled writing.

Comment: how this code is related to your question?

Comment: `container is gridlayout(0,2,10,10)..` - looks correct. It fills up all the columns in a row before starting a new row. That is it will add a component to the first column in the first row. The second component is added to the second column. The third component starts a new row. If you want components to be added in rows before starting a new column then you need a different layout manager.